# JSON LD @Website description @WebPage description

Tags: json-ld, meta-description

Good day,

I have a question. I am building a piece of code to generate a JSON LD microdata feed.
What I would like to know what should I be writing under :

**@graph -> @type : Website "description"**

And

**@graph -> @type : WebPage "description"**

I am wondering what's the exact difference between these two?
The first is probably (I think and I want to be certain) the general website description.
The second is the webpage's individual description.

But my question is too. Is this microdata description the same as the general page meta description?

So let's say :

Would become

```
{
    "@type": "WebPage",
    "description": "My webpage about a lot of things"
}
```

Or should it be? :

```
{
    "@type": "WebPage",
    "description": "This is my webpage about a lot of things and this is a little more customized description"
}
```

And should I use for :

```
{
    "@type": "WebSite",
    "description": "This is the same description as being used on the homepage"
}
```

Or should that also be a custom description for the entire page?